# Unexpected HTTP response, override forced gzip compression?

Tags: xml, http, encoding, http-headers, gzip

I am trying to request and parse an [XML-file](http://nesstar.ess.nsd.uib.no/obj/fDatafile/ESS5e02.0_F1), but the server respondes with a `gzip` Content-Encoding, even if I do not request it in my Accept-Encoding header.

Now, returning a gzipped response by default is unexpected, but not wrong. However, I do not seem to be able to request a non-gzipped response. I expected that the header

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0, deflate;q=0
```

would do the trick, but [apparently not](http://redbot.org/?id=jnzGns).

The libraries I'm using (rdflib) also fails to handle the link/XML-file, so I'm guessing the server is somehow incorrectly configured? Via the browser everything works OK, so I'm not sure.

Is there a way to override the `gzip` Content-Encoding? Or is this behavior simply incorrect?

Comment: It actually *is* expected to return gzip by default, because most browsers support gzip and it improves latency.

Comment: But `curl` and the parser are no browsers, and other servers do not seem to respond with gzipped content to them...